# PHP MYSQL Query Array Field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Ok. I'm using MySQL and PHP. I have a table called "Pictures" and a field in that table called "Tagged." This field is an array of UserIds which I imploded and stored as a string.

example: 114,159,14,334

Lets say I want to return all the rows in "Pictures" where a particular UserID, say 14, exists somewhere in the "Tagged" field's array. How can this be done?

Comment: You're headed down a bad path. Normalize the schema first. Add a UserPictureTag table.

Comment: do you have any links or suggestions as to a better approach? The pictures table is pretty small right now, but I can see how this approach might slow things down on a larger scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from pictures where FIND_IN_SET(14,Tagged);
```

Comment: this query isn't returning any results.

Comment: @rollsRLS8822:Pass the id as a first argument and column name as a second argument will work check updated one.

Answer (score 0):

Start it with a , and end with a , like this: `,114,159,14,334,` and then do a `SELECT FROM Pictures WHERE tagged='%,14,%'`

Just an idea, I really don't know... I've never done this before. Traditional blog tagging may be similar enough that you could look up some tutorials to learn from them.